# Can I rely on ISet.Add method putting the new member in last position?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using Iesi.Collections.Generic.ISet, I'm wondering how to determine if I can rely on this. I'm using .NET framework 4

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the behavior unless it was specifically stated in the function name or documentation.  Otherwise, there is no guarantee that the implementation from one version to another will not change exposing the assumptions made in your code. I imagine it is very common for framework to update implementations without changing the public interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: I haven't used `Iesi.Collections` before (and can't spot any documentation) but if it's meant to be anything like [`System.Collections.Generic.ISet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412081.aspx), the answer below is still relevant. I'd be *very* surprised if at a set interface which *did* guarantee insertion order.

The concept of "a set" is inherently unordered. Unless you're *specifically* using an "insertion order" set, you should *not* rely on it.

In particular:

- [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) may well change order in a hard-to-predict, implementation-specific way.
- [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) *does* guarantee an order - but it's element order, not insertion order. So if you insert 1, 5, 3, 6, 2 into a `SortedSet<int>` and then iterate over it, you'll get 1, 2, 3, 5, 6

Comment: Note that he is using Iesi.Collections.

Comment: @alexn: Ah, hadn't noticed that. Never seen Iesi before.

Comment: They have an implementation, [`LinkedHashSet<T>`](https://github.com/nhibernate/iesi.collections/blob/master/src/Iesi.Collections/Generic/LinkedHashSet.cs) that preserves insertion order. But it is only declared, on the interface level, as implementing the framework's `ISet<T>` interface.

Comment: @JeanHominal: Right, it's fine for *one particular implementation* to do that. But that's not the same as it being part of the interface contract itself, which would be very odd.